# Automake silent-rules (on by default?)

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

The documentation for automake's "silent-rules" option states that silent rules will be turned off by default, and will only be turned on if the user specifically asks for them when running configure:

http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Options.html#index-Option_002c-_0040option_007bsilent_002drules_007d-915

I would really love to know how to get silent rules turned on by default, and instead disabled by option. I can think of a few ways off the top of my head, but are there any especially official or clean ways you guys might know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])
```

in configure.ac immediately after initialization.

see: http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/automake/silent.html

Comment: This does not work for me, only the configure option works `./configure --enable-silent-rules`